# Applying a different Wordpress Template to a different wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I purchased a wordpress theme as shown in the url here `https://seosight.crumina.net/`. Since then i have changed my mind and browsed for ready made `templates` and happy with the template located here `https://themes.semicolonweb.com/html/canvas/demo-seo.html`

However, since i purchased the theme, can i buy and push the templates in the existing themes with minimal work or do i need a wordpress developer?

Comment: You can surely build a theme from HTML templates. There are plenty of guides online or you can hire a professional to do it.

Answer (score -2):

The short answer: no, you can't.
The themes aren't only a PHP template. The also have css and JavaScript files. And also some php custom functions.

The best way to replicate the page you like is with a designer, like Elementor, Divi, Oxygen, etc. Or better yet, with a developer :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).